# Making Shift-Tab work in Vim when running inside ConEmu

Tags: vim, keyboard-shortcuts, conemu

I have [these mappings](https://github.com/Kazark/vim-kazarc/blob/master/plugin/kazarc.vim#L53) in my initialization files for Vim:

```
nnoremap <S-Tab> <LT><LT>
vnoremap <S-Tab> <LT>gv
```

the intention is to be able to unindent with <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>-<kbd>TAB</kbd>. This works fine in GVim and VsVim, but it is not working in Vim running inside ConEmu.

However, tabbing (through file names, for example) forward with <kbd>TAB</kbd> and backward with <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>-<kbd>TAB</kbd> works fine on the command-line in ConEmu outside of Vim, so ConEmu must be doing something meaningful with the <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>-<kbd>TAB</kbd> sequence, and I don't rather not break the command-line behavior if possible (though if I had to choose I would choose the Vim functionality).

I'm having trouble determining what Vim thinks it is seeing for this key sequence. If I do <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>v</kbd> <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>-<kbd>TAB</kbd>, the result is `Î`. When I do `char2nr()` on it, I get `206`, and indeed, this seems to be Unicode character 206. This result of 206 is confirmed by `:echo getchar()` and typing the sequence. However, doing `map Î <S-Tab>` does not work.

How can I get my mappings to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Version 141216 fixes your issue.

BTW, your workaround is not needed anymore, but using several `keys` GuiMacro function is not optimal, better use sort of `keys("^[","[","Z")` or just `print("\e[Z")`.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a workaround. Unfortunately, it breaks the ability to reverse-tab through file names on the console, inserting `^[[Z` instead, so I am still looking for a better answer than this. However, it does make <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>-<kbd>TAB</kbd> work in Vim without further modification of Vim's configuration. I used ConEmu's macro feature to map <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>-<kbd>TAB</kbd> in ConEmu to the Vim escape sequence `^[[Z` (see `:set t_kB`), which it already interprets as `<S-Tab>` by default. The macro is `keys("^["); keys("["); keys("Z")`, as shown below.

[image: mapping macro in ConEmu settings window]